# 7zip move file in subfolder and change file name

Tags: php, zip, subdirectory, 7zip

I create a zip file in server and download.
It work by winrar unzip

```
 file
 |__test1
    |__ test04.txt
```

But when I unzip by 7zip with file download from window server (it work with file download from centos), result was strange.

```
 file
 |__test1
 |__test1.Test04.txt
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIrAX.png)

```
            if ($zip->open($filePath, \ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot open ' . $filePath);
            }

            $this->addContent($zip, (Storage::path($rootFolder . '/' . $folderName)));
            $zip->close();
```

```
private function addContent(\ZipArchive $zip, string $path)
    {
        /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
                $path,
                FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
            ),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
        );

        while ($iterator->valid()) {
            if (!$iterator->isDot()) {
                $filePath = $iterator->getPathName();
                $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($path) + 1);

                if (!$iterator->isDir()) {
                    $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
                } else {
                    if ($relativePath !== false) {
                        $zip->addEmptyDir($relativePath);
                    }
                }
            }
            $iterator->next();
        }
    }
```

I tried to replace SELF_FIRST with other constants but not work

Thanks for your help

Comment: The directory separator in a zip is `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substr` cannot ever return false but also you must have some file/dir name so the `if ($relativePath !== false) {}` is unnecessary.

You could try to normalize path like:

```
$filePath = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $filePath);
```

as it could make a difference.

Don't think you have something wrong in your code, there must be bug, either in 7zip or libzip which windows version of php (for 8.2 its module) use. you could try manually (without recursion) create testing archive, to see that your recursion iterator are not to blame.

Upgrade (downgrade ?) your 7zip/php/php_zip.

You could give a try to [PclZip](https://github.com/phpconcept/PclZip) which is lib written in php for zip creation/manipulation which does not use libzip.

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I solved this with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
Thank you